# Align button in a navbar with bootstrap5 and vue

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

this is the template of a view in my app,i am trying to do a simple navbar but as you can see the sign up button is non aligned with the rest of the text.What can i do?
I am using bootstrap5 and vue3.

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="60" height="60" alt=".">
        <strong>Foodmate</strong>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">Chi siamo</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Accedi</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="registerButton">Registrati</button>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<style>
#registerButton{

    border-radius: 20px;
}

</style>
```

[image]

I've tried to read the documentation but i cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the button from inside the anchor tag. You can just use the `a`, the `btn` class works with it too:

```
<a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-success" href="/signup" id="registerButton">
  Registrati
</a>
```

Here it is in the snippet.

```css
#registerButton{

    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <strong>Foodmate</strong>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">Chi siamo</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Accedi</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-success" href="/signup" id="registerButton">
                  Registrati
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```